# PHP how to tell vocabulary type in context

Tags: php, vocabulary

What I want to be able to do is tell if a word in a sentence is a noun, adverb, adjective, etc..  I looked into FreeLing, and a few other open source projects that I could find that are able to do this, just wondering if there is one that works with PHP natively, if not, do you have any suggestions on other projects like FreeLing that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be using a grammar parser.
www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, most recent updates to this are at: http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/